# Eventbrite API: The user_id you requested does not exist - with OAuth token

Tags: eventbrite

Does anyone know why when requesting /me/owned_events  with a valid token you can possibly get  "The user_id you requested does not exist".

To me it looks like an issue with the Evenbrite account - but I can find no effective way of raising a support ticket with Eventbrite for the API, so hoping someone has seen this before.

https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/users/me/owned_events/?token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX

{
    "status_code": 404, 
    "error_description": "The user_id you requested does not exist.", 
    "error": "NOT_FOUND"
}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The endpoint that you are trying to reach is in the process of being deprecated. You will want to switch to using the newer "organizations" endpoint.

GET /v3/organizations/organization_id/events

This will return all of the events owned by the user/organization.

If you are unsure of how to get the organization id you can find that here.
https://www.eventbrite.com/platform/api#/reference/organization/list/list-your-organizations

I hope this helps you move forward!
Best!

Comment: Thanks Nathan, it is strange however that for dozens of other accounts that call does work, just one account where it does not. - however I will adjust my plugon to get by organisation id to future proof it.

Comment: by using the org id for that account, indeed I can reads the events through your suggested endpoint, I will mark as answered.

Comment: @NathanTinius can you please kindly elaborate on how I can get the organization id? I've been trying to get it through the integer attached the URL address of the organizer page but I simply can't get the event list. Some IDs work with an empty array and the others simply are not found. Thank you in advance!

Comment: @UXAndre You can get the organization_id by calling the endpoint GET users/me/organizations/

Comment: @NathanTinius thanks so much for getting back to me. I will try it today!