# Eventbrite Events API now returning 404

Tags: eventbrite

I was previously using the following code to retrieve data about Eventbrite events:

```
        file_get_contents('https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/users/me/events?status=live&token=xxxxxx');
```

This was working just fine a few months ago. However when I've tried it again, I now get a "failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 NOT FOUND" error. I've checked the Eventbrite API documentation https://www.eventbrite.com/platform/docs/events and it seems that the URL structure is still correct.

This user and token definitely exists, as I can run the following code which does give valid results:

```
file_get_contents('https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/users/me/organizations?token=xxxxx')
```

What is wrong with my Events code?

Comment: hi, could be a client key issue?

Comment: Actually this solved my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53866034/eventbrite-api-the-user-id-you-requested-does-not-exist-with-oauth-token